# Curl Command (Beginners Linux)

Tags: linux, curl

I am attempting to use the CURL command to download the latest zip file (as of today it is FuelWatchRetail-03-2020.csv.zip) from [this site](https://www.fuelwatch.wa.gov.au/fuelwatch/pages/public/historicalFileDownloadRetail.jspx#).

The command I currently have is as follows:

```
curl https://www.fuelwatch.wa.gov.au/fuelwatch/pages/public/historicalFileDownloadRetail.jspx#/FuelWatchRetail-03-2020.csv.zip -o new.zip
```

The file that is output appears to be the html from the initial webpage. I can not seem to find a link to the file location I am trying to download. I have googled extensively to find a solution, however I am obviously not searching for the correct thing.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/iL6yA0Rh - too long for a comment. This line is generated by [cliget addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget) for Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to retrieve this file using a regular browser with Developer console launched, you'll notice that, when you click on the "link", it will trigger a HTTP POST request to https://www.fuelwatch.wa.gov.au/fuelwatch/pages/public/historicalFileDownloadRetail.jspx with the following parameters:

```
{
   "j_idt72":"j_idt72",
   "j_idt72:resultsTbl_rppDD":"20",
   "javax.faces.ViewState":"-4860850130551349268:6438609436745021067",
   "j_idt72:resultsTbl:0:j_idt75":"j_idt72:resultsTbl:0:j_idt75"
}
```

In return, the requested file is given as attachment:

```
{"headers":
   [
       {
          "name":"Content-Disposition",
          "value":"attachment;filename=\"FuelWatchRetail-03-2020.csv.zip\"; filename*=UTF-8''FuelWatchRetail-03-2020.csv.zip"
       },
       {
          "name":"Content-Type","value":"application/pdf"},
       [remaining data are useless for this explanation]
}
```

So it's quite impossible to retrieve the file you want without implementing a bit of "logic" around curl.
It'll probably be less painfull to implement this using a scripting language with HTTP/HTML abilities such as Perl, Python, etc...